# angular - local storage not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to store data in local storage when the app loads using the AngularJS ngStorage module.

I have the following code:

**app.js:**

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives', 'ngCordova', 'ngStorage'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    $localStorage.message = "Hello World";

  });
})
```

Then using my controller, I want to do the following.

**controller.js:**

`$scope.data = $localStorage.message;`

and finally output the saved message.

**message.html**

`<div><p> Saved Message:{{ data}} </p></div>`

When I check the local storage using Chrome Inspect tool, I dont see the stored message. Any idea how to save data from app.js at startup?

Comment: where is `$localStorage` injected?

Comment: see the answer. Use localStorage not $localStorage. Else, inject $localStorage to use it.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation :-

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ngStorage'])
    .config(['$localStorageProvider',
        function ($localStorageProvider) {
            $localStorageProvider.get('MyKey');//gets

            $localStorageProvider.set('MyKey', { k: 'value' });/sets
        }]);
```

Or

```
 localStorage.setItem('message', 'helloworld');//saves in developer tools
 $scope.getItem=localStorage.getIem('message');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the $localStorage service in your run method and also in your controller. Like this:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives', 'ngCordova', 'ngStorage'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $localStorage) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
// Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
// for form inputs)
if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
}
if(window.StatusBar) {
  // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}

$localStorage.message = "Hello World";

  });
})
```

See the third line. The run function parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `localStorage` not `$localStorage` cause `$localStorage` has to be injected whereas `localStorage` comes by default in `angularjs` and it works without you having to inject anything. I have worked on it.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    localStorage.message = "whatever";
});
```

**In Controller:**

```
$scope.message = localStorage.message;
```

**In View:**

```
<div>{{message}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare $localStorage variable like this:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives', 'ngCordova', 'ngStorage'])
    .run(function($ionicPlatform, $localStorage) {
          $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
          // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
          // for form inputs)
          if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
              cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
          }
          if(window.StatusBar) {
              // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
              StatusBar.styleDefault();
          }

          $localStorage.message = "Hello World";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i am working on ionic and used localstorage(simple html local storage function)
set value in localStroage

```
window.localStorage['Invite-Code'] = $scope.passCode;
```

above code set the value in local storage.

```
 var val = window.localStorage['Invite-Code'] || false;
```

above code show the value of localstorage value, if exist or not then its return value true or false. here 'Invite-Code' is key

Answer (score 0):

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives', 'ngCordova', 'ngStorage'])
```

Then in your **controller.js** you need to inject `$localStorage`:

```
app.controller('yourController', ['$scope', '$localStorage', function ($scope, $localStorage) {
    $scope.data = $localStorage.message;
}]);
```